# Colors and text annotations in Plotly R - interactive mode

Tags: r, plot, plotly, data-visualization, r-plotly

**Problem:** The following code produces a [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) plot which groups data based on color and annotates text on the respective y-data-points. When interacting with the plot (in the viewer pane), the selection of e.g. only model `a4` (by clicking on the line) does not work correctly as the lines disappear for all other models but the according numbers won't. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(mpg)

plot_ly(dt[model %in% c("a4", "passat")],
        x = ~year,
        y = ~displ,
        color = ~model,
        colors = "Set1") %>% 
  add_lines() %>% 
  add_text(y = ~displ, 
           text = ~displ,
           textposition = "top right",
           showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = "Anzahl"))
```

Below you can find a figure describing my problem. Once I select only a4 in the plotly chart, the passat line disappears however the numbers associated to this line remain.

**Aim:** How to modify the code such that not only the line disappears for a4/passat but also the associated numbers?
[image]

Appreciate your suggestions / inputs.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add_text` statement has the option `showlegend` as `FALSE`, which effectively hides a potential second legend that would show/hide the text/numbers.

One strategy could be to use `legendgroup` to group the two legends together for lines and text, while still hiding the text legend. The group should be assigned to `model` in this case.

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(mpg)

plot_ly(dt[model %in% c("a4", "passat")],
        x = ~year,
        y = ~displ,
        color = ~model,
        colors = "Set1") %>% 
  add_lines(legendgroup = ~model) %>% 
  add_text(y = ~displ, 
           text = ~displ,
           textposition = "top right",
           showlegend = FALSE,
           legendgroup = ~model) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = "Anzahl"))
```

**Plot**

[image: plotly plot using legendgroup]